# Can I mimic .submit's page refresh when $.post returns data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that, when submitted (via POST), tells the server to deliver a PDF. Because .submit automatically refreshes the page with the result, the PDF is then successfully loaded in the browser. This is currently working.

However, I want a callback to fire after the PDF has arrived. Asynchronously waiting for .submit doesn't work, because as far as ajax is concerned, .submit is "done" once it has posted; it doesn't care about waiting for the server. To use the callback, I need to use something else, like $.post.

$.post does not automatically refresh the page with the result, though, and while I can have my callback that waits for the data to arrive, I can't get that PDF to load in the browser like it does with .submit.

Is there a way I can mimic or force a .submit-style page refresh that loads the data retrieved from the post, within a $.post success callback?

Comment: Why would you use ajax just to refresh the page?

Comment: Short answer, no. You can grab the bytes using file API, but won't be able to open as PDF. But why do you want that? What's the problem with a normal submit that needs ajax?

Comment: @Andre Do you have a way to have a callback fire when the PDF loads, then? Because that's the problem with a normal submit, like I say in the question.

Comment: @LucasY.you can make an ajax request, just not with jQuery. See this url for more info: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery $ajax callback doesn't return until the server responds. So if you can generate the pdf file in the servers request/response cycle you can return a url and then use window.location to reload the page in the success callback.

```
window.location.assign('url returned in success callback data');
```

If you are generating the PDF asyncronously, after the server responds, then you can return the url of where the pdf will be generated.  The client can then do long polling (checking to see whether the url exists via an ajax header call)  and then change the  window location once the file appears.